# How do I insert multiple checkbox values into a txt database?

Tags: php, arrays, database, checkbox

I'm making a php form that writes the values inside a TXT database.
In the form there are several multiple checkboxes (Zona) that can be selected in more options. How can I write all the selected values in the database?

My code:

Form:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="action.php" method="post">  
    <label for="guasto">Guasto</label>  
        <input type="text" id="guasto" name="guasto" />  
   <input type="checkbox" name="zona" value="zona 1"> zona 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="zona" value="Zona 2" > zona 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="zona" value="Zona 3" > zona 2<br>
    <label for="causa">Causa Guasto</label>  
        <input type="text" id="causa" name="causa" />  
    <label for="risoluzione">Tempi di risoluzione</label>  
        <input type="text" id="risoluzione" name="risoluzione" />  

        <input type="submit" name="Salva" value="Salva" />  
    </form>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Action.php

```
include("setting.php");



/*************************
SAVE
**************************/
if(isset($_POST['Salva']))
    {
    if(!is_writable($my_database_txt)){
        exit("The file does not have write permissions!");
        }
    // 
    $bad_char = array("|", "\r\n", "\r", "\n");
        $guasto = str_replace($bad_char, "", $_POST['guasto']);  
        $zona = str_replace($bad_char, "",$_POST['zona']);  
        $causa = str_replace($bad_char, "", $_POST['causa']);  
        $risoluzione = str_replace($bad_char, "", $_POST['risoluzione']);
    // 
    $open = fopen($my_database_txt, "a+");
    // scriviamo i dati separati dal carattere separatore
    fwrite($open, $guasto."|".$zona."|".$causa."|".$risoluzione."\r\n"); 
    //   

    fclose($open);

    // 
    header("location: vista.php");
    exit;
    }
```

How can i save multiple checkbox array?

Comment: You could use a foreach to loop through all the $_POST variables. It will help you a lot if you first use `print_r($_POST);` to see what $_POST has. An example of the foreach `foreach($_POST as $currentData){ fwrite($open, $currentData . "\r\n") }`

Comment: You need `name="zona[]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use zona[] for the checkbox name so that it will store the value in array form. Otherwise, the $_POST will always return you the last checked item. Below are the complete modification

```
<html>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="action.php" method="post">  
    <label for="guasto">Guasto</label>  
        <input type="text" id="guasto" name="guasto" />  
   <input type="checkbox" name="zona[]" value="zona 1"> zona 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="zona[]" value="Zona 2" > zona 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="zona[]" value="Zona 3" > zona 2<br>
    <label for="causa">Causa Guasto</label>  
        <input type="text" id="causa" name="causa" />  
    <label for="risoluzione">Tempi di risoluzione</label>  
        <input type="text" id="risoluzione" name="risoluzione" />  

        <input type="submit" name="Salva" value="Salva" />  
    </form>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

For the Action.php file, I use implode function to glue zona using comma. Anyway, you could modify this to suit to your requirements.

```
/*************************
SAVE
**************************/
if(isset($_POST['Salva']))
    {
    if(!is_writable($my_database_txt)){
        exit("The file does not have write permissions!");
        }
    // 
    $bad_char = array("|", "\r\n", "\r", "\n");
        $guasto = str_replace($bad_char, "", $_POST['guasto']);  

        //Note: glue the array using comma through implode function
        $zona = str_replace($bad_char, "",implode(",", $_POST['zona']);  
        $causa = str_replace($bad_char, "", $_POST['causa']);  
        $risoluzione = str_replace($bad_char, "", $_POST['risoluzione']);
    // 
    $open = fopen($my_database_txt, "a+");
    // scriviamo i dati separati dal carattere separatore
    fwrite($open, $guasto."|".$zona."|".$causa."|".$risoluzione."\r\n"); 
    //   

    fclose($open);

    // 
    header("location: vista.php");
    exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with multiple `checkbox`, always keep one thing in mind. Either give them different name or name must be an array so that it can hold multiple values in it. In your case:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="zona" value="zona 1"> zona 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="zona" value="Zona 2" > zona 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="zona" value="Zona 3" > zona 2<br>
```

these 3 checkboxes have same name. When all these three are checked, the last selection override the previous selection value.

So either change their names to different names or make the name as array like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="zona[]" value="zona 1"> zona 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="zona[]" value="Zona 2" > zona 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="zona[]" value="Zona 3" > zona 2<br>
```

and you can get its value on form submit like:

```
$zona = $_POST['zona'];
```

here `$zona` is an array, use `foreach()` to get its individual elements.